# Creating a PowerShell listener to check incoming connections for specific filetypes

Tags: windows, powershell, listener

Is there a way to create a PowerShell listener script which would check inbound connections for *.exe, *.rar and *.zip files?

**What I would like to do**

EDITED: Let's say that my kid tries to download a file of a certain type, via one of the browsers or by a downloader (think Download Accelerator Plus, or JDownloader). A listener script, which is running constantly in the background, checks the incoming connections for predefined filetypes (let's say, for *.exe, *.rar, and *.zip). If there are any such files, the script checks the file header for the incoming file size. Then, if the filesize is greater than, say, 5 MB, it rejects the connection.

Please note that I'm not asking for a complete code. I would just like to know whether it's possible to make such a script with PowerShell, and, if it's not possible, some advice on how to achieve what I have in mind.

Comment: Can't say that I completely understand what you're trying to do, but you might want to research [PowerShell (Asynchronous) Event Subscriptions](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/06/16/use-asynchronous-event-handling-in-powershell/).

Comment: You would need a filtering proxy for that. A simple PowerShell script isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Do you mean something like [Squid](http://squid-cache.org)?

Comment: Squid could be used that way, yes.

Comment: I guess I could go with that, even though it's not quite what I had in mind. In any case, it's easier to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the $request.url.PathAndQuery and it will show the name and extension.

If the user is downloading then you should know the filesize or look at $buffer.length.  If they are uploading then there is $Context.request.InputStream.length

```
try{$listener.close() ; $listener.dispose()} catch{}
$listener = New-Object System.Net.HttpListener
$listener.Prefixes.Add(("http://+:80/"))
$listener.Start()
$Context = $listener.GetContext()
$request = $context.request
$response = $context.response
$buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::utf8.getbytes("Hello World")
$response.contentlength64 = $buffer.length
$response.OutputStream.Write($buffer,0,$buffer.length)

#Clean up
try{$listener.close() ; $listener.dispose()} catch{}

#Open a browser to http://localhost/BigFile.exe and press F5 to refresh browser.
$request.url.PathAndQuery
#Answer was /PSTest.exe
```